# Is there any way I can use two monitors in the console in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, console, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-server

I have recently become the proud owner of two monitors in my workspace. (Ok not owner, but you know what I mean) and I'd like to use both of them at once.

Problem is, I much much prefer to use a Linux Server console over a desktop environment.

The graphics card on the machine is a GTX295 (don't ask why, it's a long story.) so I essentially have two graphics cards. Each has a DVI output. Is there any way I can get the console to stretch across two screens? Or will I have to install a desktop Ubuntu for this to work?

Comment: Is this without X/TwinView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Linux console driver is only prepared to deal with a single video connection.

Answer (score 3):

Start X server with full-screen xterm? You can use all features of X and it should look like a linux console.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitors are connected to different Linux machines, you can start "screen" in multi user mode and switch between them.